# The answer is stranger than you think

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

From a word of five letters

Take out the ten

Scramble the remaining letters

And you will get back to ten

Hint:

> The word and what you get after scrambling have a common property

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Xenon

Take out the ten

> Remove the **X** (Roman numeral for ten)

Scramble the remaining letters

> enon -> **neon**

And you will get back to ten

> **Neon** is the tenth element of the periodic table

The word and what you get after scrambling have a common property

> Both chemical elements/ noble gases

Title

> The name xenon derives from the Greek word ξένον xénon, neuter singular form of ξένος xénos, meaning 'foreign(er)', 'strange(r)', or 'guest'.

Comment: Purpx bhg gur zrnavat bs Kraba

Answer (score 24):

Alternate answer:

From a word of five letters

> MIXED

Take out the ten

> -X -> MIED

Scramble the remaining letters

> DIME

And you will get back to ten

> a dime is ten cents

> Title refers to how things that are "mixed" become "stranger".

Comment: Clever answer. Butrot13jbeq QVZR vf abg eryngrq gb ZVKRQ-- V guvax